# Repeat subset of tests determined programmatically at runtime with gtest framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

That's orthogonal why but for clarity: I created a TimeMonitor event listener that at the end of the test compares the elapsed time with a policy and fails it if the test takes longer.

It works great with one exception - from time to time the system gets in weird state and some of the tests might take longer because of that. Note my bar for unit tests is 15ms - it is not so hard to happen.

I had this before and the way I solved it was to create a record and wait until the same test exceed the them several times before I fail it. This has several flows - the major one  - the need of persisting the data.

I think it will works better if I simply do two (or more) passes. At first pass I collect the tests that exceeded their time and in pass 2-N I repeat them to confirm or reject the problem.

My question is - how. What I need to do (if possible) to programmatically collect a subset of tests and rerun them. Do I need to remove test from `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()` or I should create another UnitTest.

A reference to something similar would be great, like retry failed tests for example.

Comment: Hmm, testing timing constraints might be a hard thing to do. There's so many variables that may influence them, varying from cosmic radiation intense to actual OS work load.

Comment: It is not so bad actually. If you move every failed because of time test to a group with other policy when you see it. It might take 100 runs before you clean all the tests that are at the edges.

Then this annoying hiccups are the problem.

Comment: Well, if I see such behavior from my tests I decide either to relax my timing constraints, or try to investigate about the problem. Depends on how frequent the fails will happen. IIRC it's not really possible to collect a set of failed tests from a test run, and rerun these programmatically. May be something is possible with a special listener.

Comment: try to use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution actually is simple (when you know it). Disclaimer not tested with every possible corner case.

in pseudo code:

```
time monitor -> just observe and create a filter for the long tests
attach time monitor

testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
int result = RUN_ALL_TESTS();

if (result == 0 && time_monitor->has too long tests()) {
    time monitor -> activate reporting errors
    ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) =  time monitor -> the filter();
    result = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the following does not directly answer your question, but I believe that a suggestion of a different approach is justified. I would suggest doing test execution time analysis from a separate process to simplify things and avoid changing the program that runs the tests. This way, you can be certain that you have not influenced the execution time of your tests by inserting additional code that keeps track of tests whose execution time exceeds the threshold you have defined. Also, you won't be needing to modify state of `UnitTest` objects and other details of `googletest` implementation, which is harder to understand and potentially dangerous.

Output of the executable that runs your test suite already provides you with execution time for each test. Write a script that runs your test suite executable once and parses that output to determine which tests take too long to execute (this can be easily achieved in some higher level language like Python). Then, if the script has found some tests that are suspicious, it re-runs the test suite executable 2-N times by specifying `--gtest_filter` command line parameter to it. For example:

`tests.exe --gtest_filter=*test1*:*test2*:...:*testN*`

This way, only suspicious tests will be re-run and you will be able to determine if some of them is indeed problematic.

If you do not want to use the values provided by `googletest`, you can modify your `TimeMonitor` to output the test execution time and parse those values. However, maybe it would be best to remove it and be 100% sure you are not influencing the execution time of the tests.

Hope this helps!